# What this software trick to list current process and write memory with current function that not documented

Tags: c#, c++, static-analysis, portable-executable, malware-detection

Can someone explain why this software can list all process and write process without  using any api function that related to that specific task? or with current function can do that things. the sofware is called ArtMoney. its a memory editor software. i can get the list that function from look the source.

the current new version called

> am800.exe

. this list the function that software use.

```
VirtualProtect
LoadLibraryA
ExitProcess
GetProcAddress
RegCloseKey
ImageList_Add
ChooseFontW
SymLoadModule64
Pie
WNetGetConnectionW
memset
NetWkstaGetInfo
IsEqualGUID
```

as we see the software have function `loadlibraryA` that means it will load other dll when running. I found the dll that software load by looking from process explorer modules. i found am800.dll that have several function.

```
SetThreadLocale
GetLastError
GetStdHandle
GetSystemInfo
SysReAllocStringLen
PostThreadMessageW
```

by looking that i don't find any related function that can list process like `EnumProcesses` and `WriteProcess`. after that i think theres again module that load before `am800.dll`. as i checked in process explorer. open 1 by 1. there's no suspicious file. this software is popular old software. so i think this developer have exprience to hide the existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoadLibraryA` loads a DLL into the process at runtime, and `GetProcAddress` returns a function pointer to a specific function in a loaded library.  Together, these two functions can be used to effectively late-bind to DLL functions.

At some point during runtime, the program is using these functions to load the libraries it needs and then get pointers to the functions it needs.  This may be to evade anti-malware detection, or perhaps it's so that the program can run on multiple version of Windows APIs that may not be compatible with each other.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to avoid malware detection; the dll open will still count as the application opening a file; and all file opens will go via the anti malware software (though most are likely pass through).

Comment: ow i get it now. btw  is there other function that like exact GetProcAddress?

Comment: @claudia I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @cdhowie i means other function that act like GetProcAddress that call function inside dll within run time. or other function that might to suspicious as a malicous code.

Comment: @claudia There may be others, but I'm not aware of any off the top of my head. `GetProcAddress` by itself is not suspicious.  There are plenty of legitimate uses for this function.  A good example would be a program that can load plugins; it would enumerate the DLLs in a directory, load each with `LoadLibraryA`, and then use `GetProcAddress` to interface with the plugin.